# Cannot read video from file while can read from camera

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, video-capture

My problem is that I cannot read from file I tried with `.mp4` and `.mov` using cpp code on windows with library opencv3.4.0. I tried to read from camera it is working. 
What could be the reason ?

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("001.mp4");

// Check if camera opened successfully

if (!cap.isOpened()) {

    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;

    break;  //==>hits here

} 


/// while below code part works correctly

cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

// Check if camera opened successfully

if (!cap.isOpened()) {

    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;

    break;  

}
```

Comment: Try [downloading a codec pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: Copy opencv_ffmpeg to the folder with your exe

Comment: The issue was about opencv_ffmpeg libraries I copied into the folder which has my exe. The issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and try below code, if it doesnt work either. It is completely about your opencv installation or directory mistake.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


   int main(){

  VideoCapture cap("videoname.mp4"); 
  if(!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  while(1){

    Mat frame;

    cap >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())
      break;

    imshow( "Frame", frame );

    char c=(char)waitKey(25);
    if(c==27)
      break;
  }

  cap.release();

  destroyAllWindows();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yunus Temurlenk, the issue is fixed as I mentioned above when I copied the opencv_ffmpeg libraries. Not sure how to select the comment as answer.